# Get count of child in firebase when view controller is showing

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a collection view with a list of matches cell and a button to add new matches. 
I'd like to have the same numbers of cell as per matches (IE: 10 matches, 10 cells) . I want the list every time the view appears.

```
var countOfMatches = [DataSnapshot]() 
viewWillAppear {
      ref.child("matches").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        self.countOfMatches = [DataSnapshot]()

        for item in snapshot.children {
            self.countOfMatches.append(item as! DataSnapshot)
        }

    })}
```

and in the collection view

```
return countOfMatches.count
```

Why my cells are not showing? I can see the results created under /matches in Firebase DB but not the cells

Comment: what is this `viewWillAppear` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `.value` instead of `.childAdded`.

Also you should reload the `tableView.reloadData()` method.

Comment: Correct Answer! Thanks! just in case..if I would like to remove the value, should I do the same or is there another method?